# open one instance of JInternalFrame at one time using hash map

Tags: java, swing, hashmap, jinternalframe

I am creating MDI application in swing I want to use hash map to display one JInternalFrame at one time. I am unable pass keys and values. I am passining key as `JInternalJframe name` and value as `object of JInternalJframe`. I am unble to proceed. I have pasted incomplete code. To make you understand.

```
import java.util.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class HashMap {
        static HashMap <String, JInternalFrame> myMap = new HashMap <>();
        //String(key) is the name of JInternalFrame
        //JInternalFrame(value) is name of object of JInternalFrame
        public static void main(String [] ashu){

        myMap.put("CityMaster",cm);
        myMap.put("TransportMaster",tm);
        myMap.put("AccountMaster",am);
        myMap.put("BankMaster",bm);

        for (String str: myMap.keySet()){
                System.out.println(str);
        }
        for (JInternalFrame jf: myMap.values()){
                System.out.println(jf);
        }
        }
}
```

I have created JInternalFrame named above as CityMaster,BankMaster, etc.

Comment: You say you are "unable to pass keys and values."  What, specifically, does that mean?  What happens when you try?  If you get an exception, please include the full stack trace of that exception in your question.  If you get a compile error, please include the full text of the error in your question.

Comment: Can you give sample code for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this out. Not much to explain. I just added some InternalFrames to a DesktopPane, as you should do. Disregard the `setSize()` everywhere. It was just for brevity, and my laziness. You shouldn't be using set size

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.beans.PropertyVetoException;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.logging.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class HashMapFrame {

    Map<String, MyInternalFrame> iFrames;
    String[] keys = {"TransportMaster", "AccountMaster", "BankMaster",
                     "GrandMaster", "WebMaster", "StackOverflowMaster"};
    JDesktopPane desktop;
    JButton button = new JButton("Add Frame");
    int index = 0;
    int x = 0;
    int y = 0;

    public HashMapFrame() {
        desktop = new JDesktopPane();
        iFrames = new HashMap<>();
        for (String s : keys) {
            iFrames.put(s, new MyInternalFrame(s, x, y));
            x += 30;
            y += 30;
        }

        button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                if (index < 6) {
                    desktop.add(iFrames.get(keys[index]));
                    iFrames.get(keys[index]).setVisible(true);
                    try {
                        iFrames.get(keys[index]).setSelected(true);
                    } catch (PropertyVetoException ex) {
                        Logger.getLogger(HashMapFrame.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                    }
                    index++;
                }
            }
        });

        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.add(desktop);
        frame.add(button, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(550, 550);
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new HashMapFrame();
            }
        });
    }
}

class MyInternalFrame extends JInternalFrame {

    public MyInternalFrame(String title, int x, int y) {
        super(title);

        setSize(300, 300);
        setLocation(x, y);
        setClosable(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: I want this only. will do

Comment: I forgot the `MyInternalFrame` class. I just added it

Comment: Its ok, I relate that thing with `JInternalFrame`. I wanted the logic and I got that thank you.